# how can I launch the "import maven project" from within my eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I have developed my own eclipse plugin that creates a new Custom Wizard. at the end of the wizard, once all the tasks are done, i want to launch the "Import maven project" wizard.

for example, for a normal project i can do something like that

```
        IWizard wizard = new ExternalProjectImportWizard(page1.getTxtPathLocation().getText());

        WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(getShell(), wizard);
        dialog.open();
```

what is the class name for the maven equivalent import wizard?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is **`MavenImportWizard`**:

```
org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenImportWizard
```

and is a part of *m2e* plugin.

---

## How to find that via Google/grepcode

1. Google `grepcode import existing maven project` 
   leads you to [plugin.properties](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.3/org.eclipse.m2e.core/ui/1.4.0.20130601/plugin.properties), where you see the following line:

   ```
   m2.wizard.import.description    =   Import Existing Maven Projects
   ```
2. In the same project in grepcode, you see the [plugin.xml](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.3/org.eclipse.m2e.core/ui/1.4.0.20130601/plugin.xml?av=f) with the snippet which contains class name:

   ```
   <wizard id="org.eclipse.m2e.core.wizards.Maven2ImportWizard"
           class="org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.wizards.MavenImportWizard"
           icon="icons/import_m2_project.gif"
           category="org.eclipse.m2e"
           name="%m2.wizard.import.name">
      <description>%m2.wizard.import.description</description>
   </wizard>
   ```

---

## How to instantiate an import wizard in a generic way

As Greg pointed out, the class is in `internal` package and should not be used directly. 
Instead, you should use Eclipse API to get *wizard descriptor* by its id, and then instantiate the wizard using the descriptor. You'll find wizard descriptor id in plugin.xml (see above). It is `org.eclipse.m2e.core.wizards.Maven2ImportWizard` in your case.

Here the code snippet which accomplishes the task:

```
final String MAVEN_IMPORT_WIZARD_ID = 
    "org.eclipse.m2e.core.wizards.Maven2ImportWizard";

final IWizardDescriptor mavenImportWizardDescriptor = 
    PlatformUI
    .getWorkbench()
    .getImportWizardRegistry()
    .findWizard(MAVEN_IMPORT_WIZARD_ID);

if (mavenImportWizardDescriptor != null) {
    final IWizard mavenImportWizard = mavenImportWizardDescriptor.createWizard();
    final WizardDialog mavenImportWizardDialog = new WizardDialog(getShell(), mavenImportWizard);
    mavenImportWizardDialog.open();
}
else {
    // Wizard not found - e.g. if m2e is not installed. 
    // Notify user. 
}
```

See also:

- http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.eclipse.jface.wizard.IWizard
- http://blog.resheim.net/2010/07/invoking-eclipse-wizard.html

Comment: Note that since this is an **internal** class you should not be using it!

Comment: Thanks Alex i'll give it a shot. @greg-449, do you have an alternative? keep in mind that what i ask for is a requirement, so one way or the other i need to launch that wizard.